# Google Auth2 giving "invalid_request" response for getting access token & refresh token

Tags: android, http-post, google-authentication

How to get the access token & refresh token for google authentication for XMPP. I get successfully the authorization code, but now I need to get the access token & refresh token. But when I do the request in Android with the underneath code I get the response:
{
  "error":"invalid_request"
}

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" );         
json.put("client_id", "128232338269.apps.googleusercontent.com" );
json.put("client_secret", "eufZ8Rmjsk1MaADYsHYW" );
json.put("redirect_uri", "urn:ieadsdg:oauth:2.0:oob");
json.put("code", res_code);
json.put("grant_type", "authorization_code");

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

Log.i(TAG, "JSON********" +json.toString());
se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
request.setEntity(se);

/* Checking response */  
response = client.execute(request);
```

but i am getting this error for that code. `Response = {
    "error" : "invalid_request"
 }`

what is the problem here. HttpPost method is the correct for this url.

Comment: Did you tried to make it a GET request and put the oauth data in the header? see http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/

Comment: I am getting method not allowed error. when i use GET method for this.

Comment: Did some simple working request and code request. Outcome they are different and indeed also give another response. Can you please explain in more detail what you are doing where you get requests from and why you build the request like this? Any reference I can look at?

Comment: ya, look at this documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp i am following this. to get access token for gtalk XMPP login ..

Comment: As I mentioned you're code request is way different and after looking into the docs you mentioned, it is not following the guidelines. You want to create a http request in your'e code like:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&
redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&
response_type=code&
client_id=812741506391-h38jh0j4fv0ce1krdkiq0hfvt6n5amrf.apps.googleusercontent.com

Comment: Already i did that first. now i have success code i have to get access token from that. so i am creating the above JSON object with params with that URL. see in documents.

Comment: So the user already granted the application and you have an authorization code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26138/discussion-between-rajareddy-polamreddy-and-qvdev)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a chat we found what the problems where. The payload wrong and the content-type was set wrong. The following code is the solution:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" );
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    //Please make this custom with you're credentials
    String requestBody = "code=123123132&client_secret=eufFgyAZ8Rmjsk1MaADYsHYW&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=128169428269.apps.googleusercontent.com";

    try {
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestBody));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    /* Checking response */
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        String results = "ERROR";
        results = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("STACK", "Response::" + results);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

Comment: Doing the same but are not that successful as @RajaReddy. Do I have to attache the HttpClient to some webview? I have the Client ID for installed applications setup just the same. Can this code run just like this and return the access_token refresh_token

Comment: Hi, no need to attach this to a webview. It is just a regular HTTP client request. This code attached above should work of you attach the wright credentials in requestBody. If not please post you're debug information.

Comment: Your probably right about the credentials in requestBody.
Created debug info at [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084363/right-credentials-in-requestbody-for-android-google-play-oauth2-gtalk-authtoken)