# Gtalk XMPP SASL authentication failed using mechanism X-OAUTH2?

Tags: android, xmpp, google-oauth

I am using GoogleTalk XMPP in my application for chatting. unable to create XMPP connection by using username and AuthToken with `Google authentication`.

Now i am using `GoogleAuth2` for `authentication`. i tried to authenticate like this using access_token and email. by using `SASLMechanism`. but i am not able to connect to xmpp serv
er, it gives error like this `SASL authentication failed using mechanism X-OAUTH2`

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server_host, SERVER_PORT, SERVICE_NAME);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
m_connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-OAUTH2", GoogleConnectSASLMechanism.class);
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-OAUTH2", 0);

config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);   
try {           
    m_connection.connect();     
} catch (XMPPException e) {         
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is the class i am using for `SASLMechanism.`

```
public class GoogleConnectSASLMechanism extends SASLMechanism {

public static final String NAME = "X-OAUTH2";

private String username = "";
private String sessionKey = "";

public GoogleConnectSASLMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
    super(saslAuthentication);
}

@Override
protected String getName() {
    return NAME;
}

static void enable() {
}

@Override
protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {

    final StringBuilder stanza = new StringBuilder();
    byte response[] = null;

    stanza.append("<auth xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\"" +
            "mechanism=\"X-OAUTH2\"" +
            "auth:service=\"oauth2\"" +
            "xmlns:auth= \"http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth\">");

    String composedResponse =  "\0" + username + "\0" + sessionKey;
    response = composedResponse.getBytes("UTF-8");
    String authenticationText = "";
    if (response != null) {
        authenticationText = Base64.encodeBytes(response, Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES);
    }

    stanza.append(authenticationText);
    stanza.append("</auth>");

    // Send the authentication to the server
    Packet p=new Packet() {
        @Override
        public String toXML() {
            return stanza.toString();
        }
    };
    getSASLAuthentication().send(p);
}

public class Auth2Mechanism extends Packet {
    String stanza;

    public Auth2Mechanism(String txt) {
        stanza = txt;
    }

    public String toXML() {
        return stanza;
    }
}

/**
 * Initiating SASL authentication by select a mechanism.
 */
public class AuthMechanism extends Packet {
    final private String name;
    final private String authenticationText;

    public AuthMechanism(String name, String authenticationText) {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(
                    "SASL mechanism name shouldn't be null.");
        }
        this.name = name;
        this.authenticationText = authenticationText;
    }

    public String toXML() {
        StringBuilder stanza = new StringBuilder();
        stanza.append("<auth mechanism=\"").append(name);
        stanza.append("\" xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl\">");
        if (authenticationText != null
                && authenticationText.trim().length() > 0) {
            stanza.append(authenticationText);
        }
        stanza.append("</auth>");
        return stanza.toString();
    }
}
}
```

How to authenticate the `Google Auth` by using SASL Mechanism ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a version working for me, using OAUTH2 tokens. The OAUTH2 scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googletalk` .

This code uses the Smack XMPP library.

The OAuth2 authentication mechanism :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.security.sasl.Sasl;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.Base64;

public class SALSGTalkOauthMechanism extends SASLMechanism {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SALSGTalkOauthMechanism.class.getName());
    public static final String NAME = "X-OAUTH2";


    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public SALSGTalkOauthMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
            super(saslAuthentication);
            log.info("Creating SASL mechanism for GTalk (X-OAUTH2)");
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String username, String host, String accessToken) throws IOException, XMPPException {
        this.hostname = host;

        log.info("Authenticating to host "+host+" with key "+username);

        String[] mechanisms = { "X-OAUTH2" };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, this);
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new AuthMechanism(getName(), Base64.encodeBytes(('\0'+username+'\0'+accessToken).getBytes())));
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
            return NAME;
    }

     }
```

And the code to make it work together :

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;

import revevol.applications.cloudpulse.client.Probe;
import revevol.applications.cloudpulse.client.ProbeClient;
import revevol.applications.cloudpulse.client.ProbeClientUtils;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;

public class GTalkProbe implements Probe {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GTalkProbe.class.getName());
    public static final String PROBE_GTALK_IDENTIFIER = "gtalkprobe";

    @Override
    public void run(ProbeClient client, Properties properties) throws Exception {
        log.info("Start running GTalkProbe.");
        long startTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
        Exception exception = null;
        MessageReboundResult result = new MessageReboundResult();
        Connection conn1 = null;

        try {
            Credential credential = ProbeClientUtils.getOAuth2Credentials(properties);

            ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
            config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
            config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);

            conn1 = new XMPPConnection(config);

            SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-OAUTH2", SALSGTalkOauthMechanism.class);
            SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-OAUTH2", 0);
            conn1.connect();

            log.info("Logging in");
            conn1.login(ProbeClientUtils.getOAuthConsumerId(properties), credential.getAccessToken());

            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            presence.setStatus("My status");
            conn1.sendPacket(presence);

            ChatManager chatmanager = conn1.getChatManager();

            String destination = "destination@gmail.com";
            log.info("Sending chat message to " + destination);
            String message = "PING : " + UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            Chat chat = chatmanager.createChat(destination, new MessageListener(//TODO : here put your stuff));

            Message msg = new Message(destination, Message.Type.chat);

            msg.setBody(message);
            chat.sendMessage(msg);

            //Here you are
    }

}
```

Comment: the URL you posted on top is not working..please post relevant working url.

Comment: Why i am getting this error in some times "SASL authentication failed using mechanism PLAIN: "

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy : this URL is not a link, it is an OAUTH scope

Comment: When i login first time it's working fine, and when i reopen my app i am unable to log in into xmpp account with same credentials had login at first time. this is the exception i am getting. "SASL authentication failed using mechanism PLAIN: "

Comment: can you help me on this issue, guide me what i have to use for keep connection alive for long time, now i am using service for XMPP connection, when user started app i am starting that service with required credentials. help me please..

Comment: David The authentication token return by the [gtalk scope above](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googletalk) how are you getting the access_token/refresh_token? Are you quering the https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token or do I send the authtoken to xmpp? @RajaReddy did you get this working?, post on your blog some tutorial if you have time

Comment: @Erik you can get those values from this https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp you have to create all urls and get those values pass them for XMPP login.by using above authentication mechanism..

Comment: very good that's what i thought to and working on getting that going looking at your [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384323/google-auth2-giving-invalid-request-response-for-getting-access-token-refres) gives grate help

Comment: @RajaReddy please [have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084363/right-credentials-in-requestbody-for-android-google-play-oauth2-gtalk-authtoken)

Answer (score -2):

I have worked much on chatting application using XMPP/Openfire server.

Here is simplest way to connect/login to the server -

```
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("abc.hostname.com",5222);
        configure(ProviderManager.getInstance());
        connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
        connection.connect();
        connection.login(userName, password);
```

To get the roster at the time of login

```
    roster = connection.getRoster();
    roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
```

Here is the configure method for the provider instance

```
public void configure(ProviderManager pm) {
    // MUC Admin
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin",new MUCAdminProvider());
    // MUC Owner
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner",new MUCOwnerProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",new StreamInitiationProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.BytestreamsProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());

    // Delayed Delivery
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:delay",new DelayInformationProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());

    //  Group Chat Invitations
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:conference", new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());
}
```

Let me know if you have any queries

Comment: My Question is related to google mechanism X-OAUTH2, i am able to create xmpp connection using username and password. but i want to create this xmpp connection with google authentication..