# Right credentials in requestBody for Android Google Play Oauth2 gtalk authToken

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, httpclient, google-oauth

Running the code below I get  "error" : "unauthorized_client". Need help pinpoint what I have done wrong.
I Want to use this in an Android app to enable Google Talk (xmpp is there already [XABBER fork](https://github.com/erikswed/xabber-android/network))
Reading [much](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) about how to do this and now come the [Google Api Console setup](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).
I have chosen
- Client ID for installed applications
- Installed application type = Other
- Enabled only the Google Play Android Developer API (green switch)

I get the authentication token from oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googletalk. (user approval screen) 
What bugs me I dont enter the SHA1 fingerprint or package name for "Other" so maybe that's the problem

code:

```
     HttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost request1 = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" );
     request1.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

     //Please make this custom with you're credentials
     String requestBody1 = 
            "code="+authToken+
            "&client_id=749825062016ia.apps.googleusercontent.com"+      
            "&client_secret=jQ1nUrAYUIBUf6hN5pwPE" +
            "&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" +
            "&grant_type=authorization_code";

     try {
         request1.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestBody1));
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     /* Checking response */
     try {
         HttpResponse response = client1.execute(request1);
         String results = "ERROR";
         results = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
         LogManager.i("STACK", "Response::" + results);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();  
     }
```

Comment: look at my Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384323/google-auth2-giving-invalid-request-response-for-getting-access-token-refres

Comment: I have looked, actually your question is my starting point. There is just something I forgot, typo or something important. What about the scope Enabled only the Google Play Android Developer API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have registered your application with type 'Android'. Then you will be asked to provide information (such as package name and certificate) that will allow the Android platform to recognize your application.

Comment: Yes that is working partly but not if I want to get the access_token and refresha_token from https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Comment: Yes the Android platform do recognize my app in the way you describe. testing the notes sample, calender sample. The code above I do get the authorization token for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googletalk but then it's a brick wall to get the access_token and refresha_token from that authorization token. I know the refresha_token is only sent first time. Any ide?

Comment: I think I don't fully understand how to use your answer with package name and certificate especially for my situation. Can you say something about that?

Comment: On Android you get an access_token directly. You can use that to call APIs. You don't need to use the /o/oauth2/token endpoint at all.